# internet connection occasionally stops, but can still ping .com sites

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, connection

every half hour or so, for 1-2 minutes my browser will stop navigating to sites, "waiting for ... to respond.."   within 2 minutes i will be able to connect to sites and browse like normal again.  weird thing is, while i cannot connect to sites, i get ping replies from any .com i type in.

this happens on my home wireless network, using FF and IE on a win7 desktop AND FF on an ubuntu laptop

the network is wpa2 secured, these are the only connections.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a wired connection instead of wireless. If it stops happening, you know to troubleshoot the wireless. If it keeps happening, it's probably your router or your ISP.

Never hurts to try power cycling your modem and router.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple checck you could open a `cmd.exe` shell and try the following command multiple times while waiting for the browser to open the page.

```
netstat -an -p tcp
```

Normally you should not get lines with `SYN_SENT`.
But, persistent existence of such lines while waiting suggests the site is taking longer to respond.

If this happens long enough, you could also try ping these IP addresses *while* your browser is waiting (within that 1-2 minute period you describe).

It would be important to differentiate that while the browser is waiting,
it is actually waiting for the site to respond and not just thrashing on your windows machine.

Another check: during this 1-2 minute time, does the browser stop responding for *any* site you try? or, is it waiting for just one specific site?
This will also help differentiate if its your browser, path to some specific site or your network connection that is having trouble in this time.

---

Update on your comment:
If its not browser, OS and web-site specific, it is very likely a glitch on the ISP end that sort-of stalls your connection for a while.

Since you move to Ubuntu and try Firefox *when* the problem hits, i suspect system load is also not related here.

If you are working over a direct Internet connection, so there are no Web-Proxies in the path,
it is odd that you can ping the web-site while your browser is stalled reaching it...

Maybe you can get a packet capture which has the ping working while you were repeatedly trying the same site from your browser.

Comment: hi,

i use windows mostly to browse, but when this happened i opened up FF in ubuntu, and sites also wouldn't load there.
so,
-it's not browser-specific
-it's not OS-specific
-it's not website-specific